# Dead Island saves are gone

Tags: dead-island

My saves are gone. Is there any way to recover them?
I got it on Steam, and after launcnhing it today the Continue options is greyed out. I played the game till almost level 10.

Answer (score 1):

First of all do check if you have enabled cloud save for this game or not in steam and if you have. If you haven't enabled it on the new PC then won't retrieve save file from the cloud, although by default it is enabled but check for confirmation.
You can check if the save games are present on the PC you played before till level 10.

Following is the location for save files for Dead Island
C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\userdata\\91310\remote\out\save\sa v_0.sav

If you can't find them here then I am afraid your save files are gone and you can not recover them.